# Laravel validation with a nested where conditions

Tags: laravel

**Goal:** Validation of a user update input with the goal to not allow a special case. A relation (role) of the user model should be checked. A user may not be assigned the role: `Visitor` with the status `0`. Everything else is allowed.

**Problem:** With my implementation of the Where conditions the validation will fail already at the first condition. So if the role is visitor, the validation fails. The second condition with the status is not considered at all.

```
users: id, name
roles: id, name, permissions, status
```

My validation rules method:

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'roles.*' => [Rule::exists(Role::class, 'id')
            ->where(function (Builder $q) {
                 $q->where('name', 'Visitor')
                     ->where('status', '!=', 0);
        })
    ];
}
```

Comment: where is the closing bracket and closing parenthesis for `where(function (Builder $q) {` ?

Comment: @N69S Thank you very much for hinting me. I updated my code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to limit `roles.*`, which I assume are `id`s from your `Role` Model's Table `roles`, you can use the `Rule::notIn()` method:

```php
public function rules() {
  return [
    'name' => 'required',
    'roles.*' => [
      Rule::notIn(Role::where('name', 'Visitor')->where('status', 0)->pluck('id'))
    ]
  ];
}
```

This will translate to `Rule::notIn([1])` (replacing `1` with whatever the `id` of the `Visitor` Role is), and if any value of `roles.*` is `1`, your validation will fail.

*Sidenote: You can do this with the `Rule::in()` too, but the query is slightly more complicated*

References:

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-not-in

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-in

Comment: Thank you Tim! One more question. Maybe i will create a new question for it. i want check instead the status the permissions. the permissions field is a json object in my maria database. It is possible to use instead where() `->whereRaw()`? I checked and i got an error. I only will check if the json has a specific pattern `{write: true}`. My try: `->whereRaw('JSON_EQUALS(permissions, ?)',
                    json_encode(["write" => true]))`